# Retry nodejs http.request (post,put,delete)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

What is the correct way to implement a retry on error/condition without using any third party modules in nodejs, please?

I'm not sure how to call the same function on the error and how to then pass the original callback/data to the newly called function?

Do I need to destroy/end the sockets?

I've tried looking for examples but have only found reference to third party modules and http.get samples which don't seem to work.  How does one test this? 
I have attempted the below without success:

```
      async pingApi(cb) {
        let options = {
        "method":"post",
         "path": `/API/pingAPI?${this.auth}`, /ect do I reference this path?
          }
        };
        let request = await http.request(options, (response) => {
          let body = new Buffer(0);
          response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body = Buffer.concat([body, chunk]);
          });
          response.on('end', function () {
            if (this.complete) {
              let decoded = new Buffer(body, 'base64').toString('utf8')
              let json = JSON.parse(decoded);
              if (json.result != 'OK') {
                setTimeout(pingApi, 1000); //cant pass callback
              } else {
                cb(null, json.result) //works
              }
            }
          });
        })
        request.end(); //does the socket need to be closed if retry is this function?
      }
```

Any help, pointing in the right direction or criticism will be greatly appreciated as I think this is a very important learning curve for me.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why are you using `await http.request()`?  `http.request()` does not return a promise so using `await` with it doesn't do anything useful.  And, using a callback with an `async` function (which by definition returns a promise) really doesn't make sense.

Comment: For a `POST`, don't you need to write some body to the request with `request.write()`?  It's unusual to do a POST with no data being sent, only a URL.

Comment: This API expects a post method for this function, however, it is not expecting any additional data other than the header.  I do use it with this API when post/put data as part of the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to call the same function on the error and how to then pass the original callback/data to the newly called function?

I don't know for sure that everything else in your function is correct, but you can fix the recursion that you're asking about by changing this:

```
setTimeout(pingApi, 1000); //cant pass callback
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.pingApi(cb);
}, 1000);
```

You aren't showing the whole context here, but if `pingApi()` is a method, then you also need to keep track of the `this` value to you can call `this.pingApi(db)`.  You can preserve the value of `this` by using arrow function callbacks like this:

```
response.on('end', () => { ... });
```

Other things I notice that look off here:

1. There's no reason to use `await http.request()`.  `http.request()` does not return a promise so using `await` with it does not do anything useful.
2. Without the `await`, there's then no reason for your function to be declared `async` since nobody is using a returned promise from it.
3. It's not clear what `if (this.complete)` is meant to do.  Since this is inside a regular function callback, the value of `this` won't be your pingApi object.  You should either save `this` higher in the scope typically with `const self = this` or all callbacks internally need to be arrow functions so the value of `this` is preserved.
4. You should probably put `try/catch` around `JSON.parse()` because it can throw if the input is not perfect JSON.
5. You should probably not retry forever.  Servers really hate clients that retry forever because if something goes wrong, the client may just be bashing the server every second indefinitely.  I'd suggest a certain number of max retries and then give up with an error.

> Do I need to destroy/end the sockets?

No, that will happen automatically after the request ends.

> How does one test this?

You have to create a test route in your server that returns the error condition for the first few requests and then returns a successful response and see if your code works with that.

---

Here's an attempt at a code fixup (untested):

```
const maxRetries = 10;

pingApi(cb, cnt = 0) {
    let options = {
    "method":"post",
     "path": `/API/pingAPI?${this.auth}`, // ect do I reference this path?
    };
    let request = http.request(options, (response) => {
      let body = new Buffer(0);
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body = Buffer.concat([body, chunk]);
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        if (this.complete) {
          let decoded = new Buffer(body, 'base64').toString('utf8')
          try {
            let json = JSON.parse(decoded);
            if (json.result != 'OK') {
                if (cnt < maxRetries)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.pingApi(cb, ++cnt);
                    }, 1000);
                 } else {
                    cb(new Error("Exceeded maxRetries with error on pingApi()"));
                 }
            } else {
                cb(null, json.result) //works
            }
          } catch(e) {
              // illegal JSON encountered
              cb(e);
          }
        }
      });
    })
    request.end();
 }
```

Remaining open questions about this code:

1. What is `this.complete` doing and what `this` should it be referencing?
2. Why is there no `request.write()` to send the body of the POST request?

---

I know you ask for no external modules, but my preferred way of doing this would be to use promises and to use the request-promise wrapper around `http.request()` because it handles a lot of this code for you (checks response.status for you, parses JSON for you, uses promise interface, etc...).  You can see how much cleaner the code is:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const maxRetries = 5;

pingApi(cnt = 0) {
    let options = {
        method: "post",
        url: `http://somedomain.com/API/pingAPI?${this.auth}`, 
        json: true
    };
    return rp(options).then(result => {
        if (result.result === "OK") {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw "try again";  // advance to .catch handler
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        if (cnt < maxRetries) {
            return pingApi(++cnt);
        } else {
            throw new Error("pingApi failed after maxRetries")
        }
    });
}
```

And, then sample usage:

```
pingApi().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much:)

"What is this.complete doing and what this should it be referencing?"
In light of points 3 I removed it :
Interestingly enough with a bit of logging it outputs the following:

pingApi() called..
....1
pingApi() called..
pingApi() called..
....0
// no OKS 

removing the this.complete:

OK called back
OK called back
pingApi() called..

Comment: @JohnathanEnslin - I added one more option to my answer.

Comment: @jfriend400 thank you.  I agree it looks cleaner, though it does have its drawbacks such as reliance on NPM and larger size due to all of the third party modules.  In my case I'm being stubborn and doing this only with pure node/javascript because I believe I will end up being a better developer in the long run.

Comment: @JohnathanEnslin - IMO, the #1 advantage of programming with node.js is the breadth and quality of all the 3rd party modules available.  If one already solves a problem you need solving, then by typing a few keystrokes, you get clean, already tested and supported code that solves your problem.  IMO, it's foolish not to take advantage of the rich eco-system.

Comment: @JohnathanEnslin - Now, I applaud wanting to learn how things work, but you can grab a module off NPM and probably learn a lot more by studying its code rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.  I learn many times faster by studying well written code by others than plodding through resolving the problem myself.  Now, you don't just grab anything off NPM and expect to to be high quality code, but if you hang out in the node.js community (the node.js tag here is part of that), then you will see various modules used over and over.  You can also see how popular something is on NPM.

Comment: @JohnathanEnslin - The request-promise module is a relatively thin layer on top of the request module and the request module is massively popular, been well supported for years.  It simply adds an enormous amount of useful stuff on top of `https.request()`, code you would just have to write yourself over and over again (like checking the `response.status` for you on every request and collecting all data from the `data` events into one buffer for you, parsing JSON for you automatically and literally hundreds of other things).  The disk size of your server app does not matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

your use of async/await with core node server intrigued me and I've tried to use much as possible of this new async features.

This is what I end up with: https://runkit.com/marzelin/pified-ping

```js
const pify = require("util").promisify;
const http = require("http");

const hostname = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
const failEndpoint = "/todos/2";
const goodEndpoint = "/todos/4";

let options = {
  method: "get",
  path: `${failEndpoint}`,
  hostname
};


async function ping(tries = 0) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    const req = http.request(options, async (response) => {
      let body = new Buffer(0);
      response.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body = Buffer.concat([body, chunk]);
      })

      const on = pify(response.on.bind(response));

      await on("end");
      let decoded = new Buffer(body, 'base64').toString('utf8')
      let json = JSON.parse(decoded);
      if (json.completed) {
        return res("all good");
      }
      if (tries < 3) {
        console.log(`retrying ${tries + 1} time`);
        return res(ping(tries + 1));
      }
      return res("failed");
    })

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    // write data to request body
    req.end();
  })
}

const status = await ping();
"status: " + status
```